# Python hmac.new is not the same as php hash_hmac

Tags: php, python, cryptography

**I would like to convert the following php code to python**

```
<?php echo(strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', $hashinput, pack('H*',$securesecret)))); ?>
```

**Using the following input:**

```
$securesecret = "5454545454545454646464646" 

$hasinput = "user_transactionid=ZXeCLFdcoiyLyONd5Ub99cUOMsFPw9kkDRdfMJY0&vpc_AccessCode=74747474&vpc_Amount=200&vpc_CardExp=2012&vpc_CardNum=4242424242424242&vpc_CardSecurityCode=323&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Currency=USD&vpc_Gateway=ssl&vpc_MerchTxnRef=22222&vpc_Merchant=52525252&vpc_OrderInfo=22222&vpc_ReturnURL=http://localhost/PHP/PHP_VPC_3DS 2.5 Party_DR.php&vpc_Version=1&vpc_card=Visa"
```

**And this is the output using php and this is correct**

```
D4A3343CB9E41BD328C67299BBCB602CDCE03E9D857C09F3BD94F2DC9112F2FE
```

**However, using python method below with the same input above produces different output.**

```
HMAC.new( force_bytes(securesecret), msg= hashInput.rstrip('&').encode('utf-8'), digestmod=SHA256).hexdigest().upper()
```

**Output from python**

```
7A935F1BE9CA69CD45C985BC2696A6DCFED9CFFD8DED86C5C8593CA974B80974
```

Why are the two methods producing different outputs?

Comment: Have you compared the binary output of `msg= hashInput.rstrip('&').encode('utf-8')` with what you get from PHP? First thing to debug these things is to split the problem up. Good title edit by the way.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have done that and the inputs are the same. The only difference is that, php msg is string and python msg is in bytes

Comment: OK, so do you know the character encoding? Usually in PHP a string *is* bytes if I'm not mistaken. Maybe you can convert the input string to hexadecimal byte representation to compare them.

Comment: I fixed the issue I need to use this funtion on the securesecret **import binascii, binascii.unhexlify(securesecret)**